# Create Dynamic Attributes / Relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am working on a enterprise web development project using C# ASP.NET MVC and one requirement from them is to have dynamic attributes, along with dynamic relationship between entities. So they want to be able to change attributes/relations without going through the hassle of changing SQL schemas/ORM classes. We are using LINQ-to-SQL.

So my question is; What would be the best way to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    var db =      @"<root>
                        <entities>
                            <entity id='1' name='tim'/>
                            <entity id='2' name='Gaui'/>
                        </entities>
                        <properties>
                            <property id='1' entityid='1' name='Age' value='46'/>
                            <property id='2' entityid='1' name='Country' value='Australia'/>
                            <property id='3' entityid='2' name='StackoverflowRep' value='17'/>
                        </properties>
                    </root>";
    var doc = XElement.Parse(db);
    var ents = from e in doc.Descendants("entity")
                select new Entity()
                {
                    id = (int)e.Attribute("id"),
                    name = (string)e.Attribute("name"),
                    Properties = doc.Descendants("property")
                                    .Where(p => (int)p.Attribute("entityid") == (int)e.Attribute("id"))
                                    .Select( p => new { name = (string)p.Attribute("name") , value = (string)p.Attribute("value")})
                                    .ToDictionary(k => k.name, v => v.value)
                };
    ents.Dump();                
}


public class Entity
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public IDictionary<string, string> Properties {get;set;}
}

// You can run this spike in LinqPad (language c# Program)

// In this example I just have a simple master detail, and the assumtion is that the name/value pairs are strings. 
// In a real app you probably would have another table with property types, something like...

//<propertytypes>
//  <propertytype id='1' Name='Country' type='string'>
//  ....etc
//  </propertytype>
//</propertytypes>

// and in the properties table you would join to this instead.

// This would give you the data types, plus the ability to 
// populate a list of allowed properties etc.
```

Comment: Wow sorry my stupidity, I meant dynamic attributes! Post edited.

Comment: Not stupid, That's kinda what I had assumed. And given that, this is indeed a "propery bag" type pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the code, mate! One question though, how is the Dictionary stored in the database? How do I create the field in DB?

Comment: This is where you just need your entity properties table, it needs to have a foreign-key to the entity table and you just join it in your query like any other master detail. The wrinkle is data typing. You might be able to do that in your ORM's mapping (not that familiar with linq to SQL)

Comment: Okay. BUT the problem is the admin picks the attributes (this is a user profile) for his users. Then the users can fill out these details. So the UserProfile table has a foreign key to a UserProfileProperties table with one-to-many relationship. Okay I get that, but when a user fills out these details, I don't know where to go from there. How is the data (picked attributes values) stored? JSON? And what if some user filled out the old attributes and then the admin changes them?

Comment: I'll extend / alter my answer to give a more complete example..give me 10-15 mins.